# SwiftMailer, Fatal error: Call to a member function Send() on a non-object

Tags: php, email, object, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send an email using Swiftmailer, but I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function send() on a non-object in x on line 20

This is my code:

```
<?php

require_once('swift/lib/swift_required.php');

$to = $_POST['email'];
if(empty($to)) {
    header("Location: index.php?error=empty");
}

echo $to;

$body="This is my message!";

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Some subject')
    ->setFrom(array('example@example.com' => 'John Doe'))
    ->setTo($to)
    ->setBody($body);
$message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath("myfile.pdf"));

$result = $mailer->send($message); // line 20

?>
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Where is `$mailer` supposed to come from in your code …?

Answer (score 1):

The error says that the $mailer object was never created, so you cannot call any  objects on it. I believe you are missing something like this before line 20:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.example.org', 25)
  ->setUsername('your username')
  ->setPassword('your password');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
```